# Role of cumulants in expression for truncation of characteristic function.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a real stochastic variable with density $f$ and characteristic function $\phi(u)$. Then by definition
$$
\phi(u) = \int_R e^{iux} f(x) d x.
$$
We want to find a truncation range $[a,b]$ such that 
$$
\phi_1(u) = \int_{[a,b]} e^{iux} f(x) d x \approx \phi(u).
$$
Denote $\{c_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ the sequence of cumulants which we assume to exist.

A [text](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/mf/users/oosterle/oosterlee/COS.pdf) I've been reading suggests to choose
$$
[a,b] = [c_1-L\sqrt{c_2+\sqrt{c_4}} ;c_1+L\sqrt{c_2+\sqrt{c_4}} ]
$$
or even
$$
[a,b] = [c_1-L\sqrt{c_2+\sqrt{c_4+\sqrt{c_6}}} ;c_1+L\sqrt{c_2+\sqrt{c_4+\sqrt{c_6}}} ]
$$
and then choose $L$ to be some number (e.g. $12$). What is the intuition about introducing cumulants here in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This choice of $[a,b]$ allows to control the approximation error because

$$|\phi_1(u)-\phi(u)|=\Big|\int_{[a,b]^c} \sin(ux)f(x)dx +i\int_{[a,b]^c}\cos(ux)f(x)dx\Big|\le 2\int_{[a,b]^c} f(x)dx$$
$$=2\cdot \mathbb{P}\{X\notin [a,b]\}$$

by the triangle inequality and the fact that $|\sin(ux)|, |\cos(ux)|\le 1$.

---

For example, if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $\mathbb{P}\{\mu-3\sigma\le X\le \mu+3\sigma\}\approx 0.9973$ and the approximation error is less than 0.0054 (for any $u$). Incorporating higher moments (if exist) is useful for fat tailed distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does higher cumulants help with fat tails?

Comment: @Henrik You have an explanation in the text: "cumulant $c_4$ is included because the density functions of many Levy processes for short maturity, T, have sharp peaks and fat tails (correctly indicated via $c_4$)".

Comment: Certainly its simply me who is misunderstanding something. I cant see what $c_4$ has to do with anything or more why it enters in this specific way. That is for me the sentence could just has well been: "Since the Levy process ... and fat tails we multiply with $\pi^3/2$".

Comment: It's just another measure of dispersion around the center of the distribution. It seems like they included $\sqrt[4]{c_4}$ in line with $\pm \sqrt[2]{\sigma^2}$ for the normal example. You can test it by yourself: simulate an appropriate model and check different specifications for $[a,b]$.

Comment: hmm. Okay. Maybe there just is not a more satisfactory explanation. It just seems a bit like handwaving to say: It works in the normal distribution to do this. To take account for other situations we add another measure of dispersion in a similar way and hope it works.